# Maven web project is not loading spring context xml file

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web.xml, applicationcontext

I have created a web project then converted it to maven project, I then configure the web.xml with cxf servlet and all the dependencies in the pom.xml file but when I run application in Tomcat nothing about spring context is loaded: it behaves like a normal web project with no spring.
Can you please tell me what is wrong?
here is my web.xml and applicationContext.xml files:

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" 
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"  
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation=" 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
     http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
     http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
<import resource="/spring-datasource.xml"/>

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.webservices.implementations" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dao.implementations"/>


<jaxrs:server id="productWebService" name="productWebService"
    address="/productServices">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="productService"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>TestCxfRs</display-name>


<listener>
    <listener-  
       class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXF Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXF Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

try add this to your web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have found that the war file is not even containing any web files or xml so I created another project with a suitable architype and the code above work just fine, spring loads by default the applicationContext.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try to put your applicationContext.xml inside /web-inf/classes/ directory of your web project. or else load it manually using any XML
>   parsers or add below lines to your web.xml 
>       contextConfigLocation
>       /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml**